# Angular api for manualley entering items for the drop downs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

I'm using [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) for searchable drop downs.This is the [angular version of it.](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/tree/master/modules/directives/jq).So my question is could you tell how can I implement a business case where if there is no item on the drop down box then user able to type it on the drop down and then it should be saved on the master table.But I think I cannot do that kind of behaviour with the above drop downs.So do you know any angular api to implement such behaviour with drop downs.I think we can do that by using [Typeahead dd](http://plnkr.co/edit/DYrSmAz61BUA7MeyeRgp).But the problem there is, it doesn't work as a drop down. Which means user cannot select a item without typing something on it.So can I have a solution for this ? Thanks.

**UPDATE : Business rule**

Actually those drop downs are for the master data.Therefore data are there for that drop downs always.If user needs to enter any non existing item to the master table then there must be a feature to enter that value manually on the drop down and when we save those data we can send that to Master table as a new record.

I have extracted this code snippet from the Typeahead dd api :

```
<h4>ngModelOptions support</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{ngModelOptionsSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="ngModelOptionsSelected" 
           ng-model-options="modelOptions" 
           uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
           class="form-control">
```

Comment: what are the use cases for when a dropdown does not have selectable options? Is this driven by a previous input selection?  Also your NG link points to an odd repo. The new location has a directive based on Select2 http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Comment: here is the project page for that https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: @jusopi Actually those drop downs are for the master data.Therefore data are there for that drop downs always.If user needs to enter any non existing item to the master table then there must be a feature to enter that value manually on the drop down and when we save those data we can send that to Master table as a new record.

Comment: @jusopi The urls which I have put is correct.I have tried the url which you have put also.But those searchable drop downs doesn't allow to enter items manually where it doesn't on the drop down selection. That is the issue on that api.